# Show Crop Tool on Imageview Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, crop

I want to show the cropper tool on an imageview to allow me to crop the image and set the cropped image as the new src of the imageview.

Let me explain properly, the image src is gotten from a file path or a gallery uri. No lifecycle method is used here. Suppose I have an imageview in xml like this:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imgView"
     android:layout_width="40dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:src="filePath or gallery URI" />
```

and in activity, I get the image file path and set the src to the image like this:

```
        imageFilePath = bundle.getString("image_challenge_camera");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath);
        cropImgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

and also the uri in same way. How do I crop the existing image on the imageview. If so, how do I get the crop output image or data?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when cropping, create a copy of bitmap of your original image that you've got from that path and then crop or modify it to save.

[you can use this library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

Comment: I'm confused what value to set as intent data in this line: CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data); as my uri is not from intent. What should I do?

Comment: They have a very well documented wiki [https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/wiki/Using-built-in-CropImageActivity] Read it carefully hope you'll understand

Comment: When I try to build my app, it shows this error - Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex. This happened shortly after including the library.

Comment: @Andromeda please google with this error, there are lots of reason for that error may be for your top-level gradle or the library itself using appcompact version that is greater than your app.. and so on.I've seen your previous all question those are the very silly question to ask on StackOverflow there are a ton of answer about them previously. try yourself first, this community for helping people not tutorial site.

Comment: I have checked on google. Silly questions only cos you don't understand them. I have encountered this problem before and solved with multiDex dependency and in defaultConfig. It's just not working now. Anyways, thanks for your kind comments.

Comment: if you have solved before then why you can't solve now? it's might you didn't learn that properly. For simple question try to find out tutorial first, have a look here how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask